# Refactor a huge form with a Javascript Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a huge form divided into sections. It has about eight sections and it will simply be unwieldy to put this giant form on one page. No one would ever slog through it.
I also decided that dividing it into pages will also not be ideal because if someone is section 6 and realizes he needs to change something on section 2.

I created a client side solution using Jquery. So You just click tabs representing sections of the form. So you hide a previous section section when you click on a new section and handle all the logic of saving server side making sure someone can switch back and forth while validating data on each section. Behind the scenes its still one huge form. A lot of Jquery is used to make it work properly. It is tightly coupled to the DOM and no one can understand the code unless I explain.

Also when making changes you have to make sure there are no lingering events which cause something unexpected to affect another section of the code.

Its quickly becoming a monster. I think this is an ideal problem a Javascript framework would solve but I have no idea where to start. How would it fit in the context of Javascript MVC especially all the DOM manipulation and event driven approach I use. any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org)

This is a real war story - I was struggling with the exact same issue you are. Huge unwieldy form, needed it to be refactored into re-usable components(since one portion of the form included a pricing page).

Getting started is pretty easy, I'd suggest to look at the tutorial before you see my solution.

Here's how I solved my issue  -

1. Have one controller for your form.
2. Use [UI-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for making sub-routes of your form (e.g. `/signup/profile`, `/signup/address` etc); all of them being controlled by your main controller. Store them in separate HTML files as templates being rendered on a view (yay!)

Also, you don't need a major commitment to use angular, you can just use it for this purpose in your app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Frameworks that handle data binding and embedded control statements sound like they would be ideal for an issue like this, like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/).

For example, with knockout, you could have a segment like:

```
<div data-bind="if: someCondition">
    Only show this section of the form if the condition is met
    ....
</div>
```